# Oauth of instagram from facebook app (iframe)

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, instagram

I am trying to make a facebook game using a facebook tab (iframe) and when I try to redirect my user to the authentification of Instagram I have this message :

```
Refused to display "my_url" in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Does anyone know how can I make an Instagram connect from a facebook iframe?

I use this library : https://github.com/galen/PHP-Instagram-API

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to make a target of my link to log in with Instagram :

```
<a href="instagram_oth_url" target='_top'>Connect with instagram</a>
```

When a user click on this link.

I configured my instagram app to redirect to my website wich redirects to the facebook tab. When a user is redirected to my website, I keep in session that the user were successfull log in with instagram.

And when the user displays the facebook tab, my iframe will load my website homepage. At this step, I check if the user should be redirected to the instagram success page.

Comment: Does this mean that the url contained within the href attribute contains your Instagram client_id?

Comment: @SteveWeaverCrawford Yes. According to [docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) client-id must be supplied as URL parameter.